Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource : Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;
I trying to start my project and following next error:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [�����: ������������ "postgres" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)] [n/a]

My application.yml:
(I sure that username and password are correct)
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/notes_db
    username: postgres
    password: 0102
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        boot:
          allow_jdbc_metadata_access: false
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

Debag:
D:\Users\Alisher\.jdks\openjdk-22.0.2\bin\java.exe -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:52671,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:D:\Users\Alisher\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2024.2\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug.enable.creation.stack.trace=false -Ddebugger.agent.enable.coroutines=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\ProjectsJava\Notes\UserService\target\classes;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.3.2\spring-boot-starter-web-3.3.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.3.2\spring-boot-starter-3.3.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.3.2\spring-boot-3.3.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.3.2\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.3.2\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.3.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.5.6\logback-classic-1.5.6.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.5.6\logback-core-1.5.6.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.23.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.23.1.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.23.1\log4j-api-2.23.1.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.13\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.13.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\2.2\snakeyaml-2.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.3.2\spring-boot-starter-json-3.3.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.17.2\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.17.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.17.2\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.17.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.17.2\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.17.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\3.3.2\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.3.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.1.26\tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\10.1.26\tomcat-embed-el-10.1.26.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\10.1.26\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.26.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.1.11\spring-web-6.1.11.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.1.11\spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.34\lombok-1.18.34.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\4.0.2\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\2.1.3\jakarta.activation-api-2.1.3.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.14.18\byte-buddy-1.14.18.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.1.11\spring-core-6.1.11.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.1.11\spring-jcl-6.1.11.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\6.3.1\spring-security-core-6.3.1.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\6.3.1\spring-security-crypto-6.3.1.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.1.11\spring-aop-6.1.11.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.1.11\spring-beans-6.1.11.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.1.11\spring-context-6.1.11.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.1.11\spring-expression-6.1.11.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.13.2\micrometer-observation-1.13.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.13.2\micrometer-commons-1.13.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\3.3.2\spring-boot-starter-security-3.3.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\6.3.1\spring-security-config-6.3.1.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\6.3.1\spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\3.3.3\spring-data-jpa-3.3.3.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\3.3.2\spring-data-commons-3.3.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\6.1.11\spring-orm-6.1.11.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\6.1.11\spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\6.1.11\spring-tx-6.1.11.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.13.0\antlr4-runtime-4.13.0.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.13\slf4j-api-2.0.13.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\3.3.3\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.3.3.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\3.3.2\spring-boot-starter-aop-3.3.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.22.1\aspectjweaver-1.9.22.1.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\3.3.2\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.3.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\5.1.0\HikariCP-5.1.0.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\orm\hibernate-core\6.5.2.Final\hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\3.1.0\jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\2.0.1\jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.5.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.5.3.Final.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\6.0.6.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.6.Final.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\io\smallrye\jandex\3.1.2\jandex-3.1.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.7.0\classmate-1.7.0.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\4.0.5\jaxb-runtime-4.0.5.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-core\4.0.5\jaxb-core-4.0.5.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\angus\angus-activation\2.0.2\angus-activation-2.0.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\4.0.5\txw2-4.0.5.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\4.1.2\istack-commons-runtime-4.1.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\jakarta\inject\jakarta.inject-api\2.0.1\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\6.1.11\spring-aspects-6.1.11.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.7.3\postgresql-42.7.3.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.42.0\checker-qual-3.42.0.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\io\jsonwebtoken\jjwt\0.9.1\jjwt-0.9.1.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.17.2\jackson-databind-2.17.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.17.2\jackson-annotations-2.17.2.jar;D:\Users\Alisher\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.17.2\jackson-core-2.17.2.jar;D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.0.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.example.UserService.UserServiceApplication
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52671', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.2)

2024-08-28T09:49:59.007+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] c.e.UserService.UserServiceApplication   : Starting UserServiceApplication using Java 22.0.2 with PID 5208 (D:\ProjectsJava\Notes\UserService\target\classes started by Alisher in D:\ProjectsJava\Notes\UserService)
2024-08-28T09:49:59.013+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] c.e.UserService.UserServiceApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-08-28T09:50:00.270+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-08-28T09:50:00.386+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 102 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interface.
2024-08-28T09:50:01.441+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-08-28T09:50:01.461+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-08-28T09:50:01.461+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.26]
2024-08-28T09:50:01.557+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-08-28T09:50:01.561+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2451 ms
2024-08-28T09:50:01.860+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-08-28T09:50:01.962+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.5.2.Final
2024-08-28T09:50:02.014+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-08-28T09:50:02.577+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-08-28T09:50:02.629+05:00  WARN 5208 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: PostgreSQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2024-08-28T09:50:04.244+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-08-28T09:50:04.272+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-08-28T09:50:05.616+05:00  WARN 5208 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 28P01
2024-08-28T09:50:05.616+05:00 ERROR 5208 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : �����: ������������ "postgres" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)
2024-08-28T09:50:05.632+05:00 ERROR 5208 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [�����: ������������ "postgres" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)] [n/a]
2024-08-28T09:50:05.636+05:00  WARN 5208 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [�����: ������������ "postgres" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)] [n/a]
2024-08-28T09:50:05.640+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-08-28T09:50:05.682+05:00  INFO 5208 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-08-28T09:50:05.734+05:00 ERROR 5208 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [�����: ������������ "postgres" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)] [n/a]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1806) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at com.example.UserService.UserServiceApplication.main(UserServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [�����: ������������ "postgres" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)] [n/a]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [�����: ������������ "postgres" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)] [n/a]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.getIsolatedConnection(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlString(Helper.java:233) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlStrings(Helper.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:476) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropConstraintsTablesSequences(SchemaDropperImpl.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1429) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1506) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: �����: ������������ "postgres" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:698) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:207) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:273) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:446) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:298) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:137) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:360) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:461) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:550) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:98) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:111) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:437) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    ... 42 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52671', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1



Pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>UserService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>UserService</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Model of user:
package com.example.UserService.models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.Collection;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    private String password;

    @ManyToMany
    Collection<User> friends;

    @ManyToMany
    Collection<Role> roles;
}


Model of Role:
package com.example.UserService.models;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
}


Earlier I had following next error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null

To solve it i added in my application.yml next code:
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        boot:
          allow_jdbc_metadata_access: false

I think this two errors may be related

As a first step you should fix encoding of your log file.

Judging by logs you have authorization problem. Check your password and permissions.

I solved my problem.
Solution:
I used postgres from docker instead of regular postgres
docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:16.4
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: notes_db
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 0102
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"

In application.yml I changed using port to connect to postgres and deleted next property:
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        boot:
          allow_jdbc_metadata_access: false

Changed application.yml:
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/notes_db
    username: postgres
    password: 0102
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect


So the problem was a faulty postgres local install?

Make sure your PostgreSQL server is up and running on localhost:5432.

Yes, it is. Now I thinking may it be because postgres installed on disk D? I have whole windows on disk D

In my opinion, your answer is more a suggestion rather than a definitive answer which actually resolves the posted question. I believe OP would have checked that PostgreSQL server is running before they posted their question. Hence I consider your answer to be a comment. Please don't post comments as answers because you don't yet have comment privilege.
